# How to replace a variable based on a local and subtraction

Tags: replace, stata

In one line, I would like to perform an operation on a specific row, the row of which is referenced by a number created by a local subtracting a number.

Here is a MWE:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
*save the number of observations in a local (is there a quicker way to do this?)
count
local N = r(N)
*make sure it works
di `N'
*make sure that the subtraction works
di `N'-1
*make the replacement, which works when referencing row with `N'
replace make = "def" in `N'
*here is the problem - subtracting from `N' doesn't work
replace make = "abc" in `N'-1
```

Error:

```
'74-1' invalid observation number
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this.

1. Create another local macro:

```
local Nm1 = `N' - 1 
replace make = "abc" in `Nm1'
```

2. Force evaluation of an expression on the fly:

```
replace make = "abc" in `=`N'-1'
```